# Как разрешить чтение только в определенной беседе вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть бот, который должен читать сообщения только в определенной беседе вк. Как реализовать эту систему чтения?

Comment: проверять ид беседы ивента, откуда он пришёл

Answer (score 0):

Как я помню у каждой переписки есть peer_id, и если ты получишь peer_id нужной тебе беседы и будешь сравнивать, то что peer_id == айди беседы, то делать действия...

Comment: а как его можно получить?

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то например на vkbottle, можно вот так получить: 

from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from config import token # в файлике config.py есть строчка token="" в скобках токен бота

bot = Bot(token)

@bot.on.message()
async def some_name(message: Message)
    await message.answer("Peer_id = " + str(message.peer_id))

bot.run_forever()